# Is it possible to loop through a link list to check for 2 attributes(2 strings) within a specific link?

Tags: java, list, hyperlink, while-loop, operator-keyword

The link has a String, integer and string. My aim is to check for the first and third string using this while loop and short circuit operator.

Lines path1 = new Lines("C1",1,"B1",null);

### Lines path1 = new Lines("C1",1,"A1",null);

```
 Lines curNode = head;

while (curNode.next != null && !curNode.L1.equals(line1) && !curNode.L2.equals(line2) ) 
{
    curNode = curNode.next;
}
```

However what this while loop does is, the first condition is met but the second isn't. For instance if i'm looking for the String "C1" AND  "B1" i get "C1" AND "A1". The way i see it is, once it comes across the first condition the second is ignored.

Is this at all possible or is there a different approach in doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
while (curNode.next != null && !curNode.L1.equals(line1) && !curNode.L2.equals(line2))
```

The issue is that if either these `equals()` are true, then your loop won't continue (due to the negation), but you want to continue unless both of the `equals()` are true, so do the following:

```
while (curNode.next != null && 
       !(curNode.L1.equals(line1) && curNode.L2.equals(line2)))
```

Comment: @user3052409 No problem, good luck!  Hopefully my answer/explanation makes sense.